# How to retain a value overwritten by the instance state restoring mechanism?

Tags: android

In my application, I have a `Spinner` whose `onItemSelected` initializes the value of a class member, say, `a`, to its default value of `0`. The user may then perform steps to change the value of `a`. I am saving the value of `a` in `onSaveInstanceState` and restoring it in `onRestoreInstanceState`. However, apparently as a result of restoring of the `Spinner`, its `onItemSelected` gets called and puts `a` back to zero. I want the value entered by the user to be preserved.

Note, however, that the old value of `a` would not make sense in any other setting of the `Spinner` (hence zeroing it upon item selection). Unfortunately, it is also hard to validate it. So, not knowing that the call to `onItemSelected` was fake, putting `a` to zero is inevitable.

The problem is that the input event handler seems to be put into some queue and called *after* `onCreate` / `onRestoreInstanceState` is finished (twice, which is another thing I don't understand). My question thus is, at what moment should I restore `a` to the non-default value from the saved instance state? Should I put this task at the end of the input event queue somehow? Or is there a way of distinguishing whether the call of `onItemSelected` happened as a result of an actual user input or just instance state restoration?

Code example:

```
private String KEY = "(...).A";
private int a;

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View childView, int position, long id) {
  /* other important stuff */
  a = 0;
  Log.d("info", "a zeroed");
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
  state.putInt(KEY, a);
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
  a = state.getInt(KEY, a);
  Log.d("info", "a restored");
}
```

After a change of orientation, the log says

```
info  a restored
info  a zeroed
info  a zeroed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with so far. It does the trick without counting off two calls of `onItemSelected` found by a mere observation. However, I still consider it a workaround:

```
private String KEY = "(...).A";
private String SEL = "(...).SEL";
private int a;
private int sel = -1;

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View childView, int position, long id) {
  /* other important stuff */
  if(position != sel) {
    a = 0;
    Log.d("info", "a zeroed");
    sel = position;
  } else
    Log.d("info", "a kept");
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
  state.putInt(KEY, a);
  state.putInt(SEL, sel);
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
  a = state.getInt(KEY);
  sel = state.getInt(SEL);
  Log.d("info", "a restored");
}
```

After a change of orientation, the log now says

```
info  a restored
info  a kept
info  a kept
```

The bad thing about this solution is that `a` has its value in the time when the `Spinner` is still uninitialized, which does not cause problems at the time being, but should never happen. A proper solution should let `onItemSelected` do all of its work and set `a` after that.

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that I didn't follow everything that you were saying in your question, however restoring a Spinner's selection is easy enough:

1. In your `onItemSelected()` use: `a = position`,
2. At the end of `onRestoreInstanceState()` call `spinner.setSelection(a);`

Understand that *every* time Spinner changes its selection the Spinner calls `onItemSelected()`, including inside `onRestoreInstanceState()`. However since you are keeping `a` set to the current selection, this isn't a problem.

Comment: Sorry I was being unclear. `a` is not the position of the selected item, it's some other data. To reduce the confusion, let `a` be a String now. Let's say that in position `0` of the spinner, the user enters some English text in it and in `1`, he enters German text. I want to avoid the situation where the text in `a` is German while the Spinner says "English", so I delete the text whenever the language is changed. But a state restoration acts like a change, too, deleting my text even though it is in the correct language.

Comment: If you only want to ignore the first call to `onItemSelected()` (when the state is restored), use a boolean to ignore the first call. See Johnny Doe's answer.

Comment: It's called twice, actually (`onCreate` and `onRestore...`, maybe??), so I would need to ignore both. I don't know if this is a rule, though. I made a more detailed comment on @Johnny Doe's answer on why this would not work.

Comment: It's odd that it is called twice, but I cannot guess why this is happening without seeing your code. However you can easily use an Integer to skip the first two times `onItemSelected()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean trigger = false;
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View childView, int position, long id) {
if (trigger){
    a = 0;
   Log.d("info", "a zeroed");
} else trigger = true;
}
```

It looks like simplest solution

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't use this solution. The function already gets called twice in a row, albeit both with the restored value (see above). So I'd have to count till `2` with the `trigger`.
As I don't know why this happens, I can't be sure it's not specific to my version or environment – the same function could very well be called thrice or just once on a different device and my trigger wouldn't work.